# jQuery ui Tooltip with ajax call not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

I've this code for tooltip on confirm button when first 2 users add a comment :

```
        $("#confirm").tooltip({
                    content: function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '/comments/numUsers.json', 
                                    data: {draw_id : $("#PostId").attr('value')},
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(data){

                                        onSuccess(data);

                                     },
                                    error: function(){
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                });

                                function onSuccess(data){
                                    if (data < 2){
                                        if(data == 0){
                                            return "You're the first user";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            return "You're the second user";
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else{
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                }

                    }
                });
```

numUsers.json return the number of users which had already commented on the post. The ajax call work ad the "onSuccess" function was called correctly , but no Tooltip was shown on my button :-( any suggestions ? thx in advance

Comment: whats your console showing?

Comment: i do not think you can put you function onSuccess() inside the function tooltip()

Comment: nothing friend. I try to console.log(data) and I correctly see the number of users returned by the numUser.json call.

Comment: Why don't do it the opposite way? Make the ajax call and in the `success` callback apply the `tooltip` function.

Comment: @harikrish i try to put it outside, but it not works :-(

Comment: @senyorToni it could be a solution but I don't understand why my code not work.

Comment: did you try making the request synch?

Comment: @arjuncc no, what is the code ?

Comment: before that, are you sure your  onSuccess(data); method is get invoked after the data is been received? can you put an alert in 'onSuccess' and display the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re is a way to perform synchronous request

Comment: @arjuncc the alert in the onSuccess() function display the cotrrect value on users.

Comment: @arjuncc I try the async request just now. Not work .